# Storing a popup message when an action is performed in Selenium & JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, popup, testng

I am trying to run a TEST in TESNG and i want to know if a popup with a specific text is thrown in screen.

I'm kinda new to Selenium and JAVA

When i click on a button an action is performed and if it went alright i got this message (this is the element):

`<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible alert-auto-dismissible" role="alert"><span>Company.-007989 has been approved</span><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button></div>`

In this case `Company.-007989` varies depending on the customer.

---

How can i do to store the message somehow to see if my TEST run alright?.

I want to know if i got some popup within the text `"has been approved"`. Is there any way?

I tried to store the popup message but nothing really worked

Comment: Which element locator you are using?

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML code you have shared of your popup, your success message resides in `span` tag so you should target span with the help of xpath. You can create custom xpath as well, in your case `//div[@role="alert"]/span` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this code works:

```
// Find popup by xpath:
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@role="alert" and contains(text(),'has been approved')]") WebElement popupAlertText;

// Wait till popup alert is displayed:
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(seleniumDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(1000));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(popupAlertText));

// Get the value shown in the popup message and store in a string:
String popupAlertTextValue = popupAlertText.getAttribute("span");
```